# Are there 506 different towns in "Boston house prices dataset"?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

This code is to load the housing data from the scikit-learn library.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
>>> boston_dataset = load_boston()
>>> len(boston_dataset.data)
506
```

First feature is CRIM which means "per capita crime rate by town".

Does it indicate that there are 506 different towns in "Boston house prices dataset"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** No, there are only 92 distinct towns. There are 506 Census Tracts.

You can run  `getattr(boston_dataset, "DESCR")` to get the description of the dataset. 
While it does not directly contain the information that you want, it does tell you:

> This dataset was taken from the StatLib library which is 
>   maintained at Carnegie Mellon University.
>
> The Boston house-price data of Harrison, D. and Rubinfeld, D.L.
>   'Hedonic prices and the demand for clean air',
>   J. Environ. Economics & Management,
>   vol.5, 81-102, 1978.

If you can get a copy of the paper, you will find in it the line:

> The physical changes in NOX concentrations in each of the 506 Boston SMSA
>   census tracts were calculated for 1990 using the Transportation and Air Shed
>   Simulation Model (TASSIM ).

If you go to the Statlib site: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/ 
You will see datasets called `boston` and `boston_corrected`. It appears that the data in sklearn.datasets is the `boston` set.  The `boston_corrected` data contains a field for the town.  My count is that there are 92 distinct  values in that field.